# admin/content customizing

Tags: 7

I need to add some new filters to the admin/content (or admin/content/file) page. Standardly, it offers me just type and status. Let's say, I would like to add the filter "name", that shows just the files of specified author. I am able to generate all the possible authors (their names) from SQL table, as well as showing them on the page (simple add it to `$form['filter']['filters']['status']['filters']` with hook_form_alter function).

But now I do not know, what to do next. The submit button calls some function to generate some filters (but then it seems pretty difficult to change everything).

Do you know any way to do that?

Comment: You should be able to create a Views page and override the current one. That's likely the easiest solution.

Comment: It might be the easiest solution, however I am not able to make even similar site, because of the admin/content/file page complexity (it would take a pretty long time to do so)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module. It comes with views based listing. Which can be easily modified based on our requirements.

Comment: Don't you know any page with some example of how to use this admin-views module? I could not found any good.

Comment: You just have to enable the module and content list is replaced itself. Some more details are given at https://www.drupal.org/node/2001212

Comment: It seems good, but I have a problem, because: "Replaces all system object management pages in Drupal core with real views." But I do want to change just one page and the other left unchanged (they're already customized, so no change is allowed). Do you know, if it is possible to change just one page with admin-views?                                        EDIT: I cloned the view, that admin-views created and disabled admin-views and the cloned view seems to stay. Let's hope, it will be good :D